# Chunky interface meaning

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

In the book of application architecture design, which I'am reading, I've found the following statement:

> "To reduce round trips and improve
>   communication performance, design
>   chunky interfaces."

Can anybody explain me what does "chunky interface" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it refers to the amount of data transferred in one call. For example, if you wanted to get a set of data from a server, instead of asking

```
GetRecord(1);
GetRecord(2);
GetRecord(3);
GetRecord(4);
```

you'd design a batch method, like

```
GetRecords(1,4);
```

The idea is that the first design incurs four lots of overhead, but the second only one.

Answer (score 1):

A chunky interface is one where you minimise the amount of separate calls whilst accomplishing a task by maximising the work done by each call.

Here's an [overview of chunky interfaces](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1045340.html).