# Doing multi-threading jobs inside AutoCAD .Net plugin

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, autocad

I am aware that Autocad APIs are not supposed to be called/used in multi-threading. But how about doing a multi-thread job(in an Autocad .Net plugin) that does not involve any specific Autocad calls/type?

The situation is like this:
1.some CAD polylines are fetched through APIs, their properties that are of interest are wrapped in custome types and then
2.In another layer some multi-thread calculations are done against these custome types.
3.The application custome types writing their results back to the CAD polylines through Autocad APIs.

Only step two is done in multi-threads.

The application uses StartTransaction() method to get the Transaction object. I haven't experienced any crashing so far for many years. But now I am trying to use StratOpenCloseTransasction() it crashes many times. Specially it crashes when Editor.Rengen() is called as I think it goes through every object in database and perhaps some are corrupted. I did narrow down the problem and one of the causes apparently is this multi-threading.

Is there any reason that CAD should crashes in calling multi-threads although no APIs is engaged? Am I safe to use multi-threading in this way?
Does StartTransaction() handles objects better than StartOpenCloseTransaction in terms of disposing them? As I didn't experience crashing on that.

Many thanks

Comment: I have just experienced some errors on `Editor.Regen`. It was due to transients entities.

Comment: What do you mean by "transients entities", Maxence?

Comment: Transient entities are temporaries entities (not associated to a database) drawn with the TransientManager class. An example of this kind of entities is the view cube. During regen, these entities are refreshed. The TransientManager can only operate on the active document. May be that with your background processing AutoCAD is confused about the active document.

Comment: @Maxence  Many thanks for the hint. I don't use transient entities. I couldn't/didn't get to the bottom of it at the end and changed it to StartTransaction method as you did suggest too. For some reason using the StartOpenCloseTransaction method for inserting entities had corrupted their colors on the drawing as if they are no more valid entities.  I think that's why Regen was throwing exception. I never experienced this with StartTransaction for years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big challenge about multi-thread is to sync back with the main thread (AutoCAD thread). Of course, assuming you don't pass any AutoCAD type/data/object to another thread (only pure .NET/C++ data).

Being aware of the risks, you can sync back with the approach described at this PDF: http://aucache.autodesk.com/au2011/sessions/2526/class_handouts/v1_CP2526_Taget.pdf

Here is the main piece of code to check if AutoCAD can receive external calls:

```
bool isQuiescent(AcApDocument* pDoc = curDoc())
{
return ( (pDoc != NULL)
 && pDoc->isQuiescent()
 && ((pDoc->lockMode() == AcAp::kNotLocked) ||
 (pDoc->lockMode() == AcAp::kNone))
 && (acedCommandActive() == 0) // no script or lisp is active
 && (acDocManager != NULL)
 && (acDocManager->inputPending(pDoc) == 0)
 && (::GetInputState() == 0)
 );
}
```

Comment: This sample code in this document is not realistic. I don't see a user launching a command, then continue to work while the processing is done in the background and suddenly see objects appear in his drawing! What I do in this situation is displaying a notification, then process the result of the computation when the user click on a link in the notification bubble. [IMPORTIGES command](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocadarchitecture/enu/online-help/ARCHDESK/2012/ENU/pages/WS1a9193826455f5ff-4e14fac512c3c6d4e7e-7eaf.htm) works like that.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know whether this piece of code and registering/handling the window message has to be in C++, and then called in c#? Or can we simply do the above checking on c# and if true then conclude that it's safe to call the CAD APIs on the main thread.

Comment: this code suppose to tell you when AutoCAD is ready to receive back calls. the link PDF should have more details.

Comment: In the managed AutoCAD API, there is a `Application.IsQuiescent` property. Not sure it's equivalent to this C++ code. There is also a `Editor.IsQuiescent` property.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `StartOpenCloseTransaction`? There is a little bit performance gain, but standard transactions are more safe. The problem with OpenCloseTransaction is that nobody know exactly how it works. The only documentation is:

> behaves similar to a Transaction object, that wraps the Open and Close methods of an object making it easier to close all opened objects instead of having to explicitly close each opened object. Recommended for use in support or utility functions that might be called an unknown number of times, and used when working with most event handlers.

which is not very clear...

I'm using it only in event handlers where objects are in flux when I need to start a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question posted in the below link is why I've used StartOpenCloseTransaction.

Comment: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/autocad-transaction-and-multi-layer-application/m-p/5736895#M45340

Comment: If you are out-of-process, the marshalling of your calls from your application to AutoCAD will slow down your application more than using several transactions. What you need is a [chunky interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687349/chunky-interface-meaning).

Comment: Well I was using StartTransaction in a chunky way: passing all the objects & committing the transaction in one go(if that's what it means).

Comment: When you say "standard transaction are more safe", (by which, I suppose, you mean StartTransaction() method) is there any evidence/proof/reason for that?

Comment: At least two: OpenClose transactions cannot be nested and they cannot be accessed via Database.TransactionManager.TopTransaction (you cannot also use ObjectId.GetObject, which is convenient way to open an object). Instead of safe, I should have use the word "convenient".